# Concatenate varying number of lines using regex

Tags: regex

I'm going to post a simplified version of my problem so please let me know if you would like more detail.

I have a flat text file containing text similar to a log file. It contains what should be 541 lines beginning with a 9-digit number and followed by various bits of data. Some of this data is XML, much of which contained extra new line characters that caused these lines to get split up and now has the file at ~30k lines. I want to concatenate this file back down to 541 lines, essentially consolidating any lines that don't start with the 9-digit number onto the previous line.

First off, the 9-digit numbers begin with '11' so I've run a match on `11\d{7}` and gotten exactly my 541 matches (ie, there are no matching numbers in my file that might match incorrectly). I've also been able to match all lines that don't begin with this number with `^(?!11\d{7})(.|\n)*$`. I would like to concatenate all those lines together, as well as tack that onto the line before (which is the line that begins with 11\d{7}). My searches online have only found solutions with finite and/or consistent numbers of lines to concatenate but this XML varies in length and structure. Finally, there is XML in this file that **is not** split across lines so matching and consolidating all XML indiscriminately isn't really an option either. Suggestions are greatly appreciated. Here's an example to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

Before:

```
117337909,some text,42930842,misc data,<xmlRoot>
<parent1>
<foo>data</foo>
<bar>123</bar>
</parent1>
</xmlRoot>
116425348,some more text,2df34as,blah,<xmlRoot>
<parent2>
<foo>data</foo>
<bar>123</bar>
</parent2>
</xmlRoot>
```

After:

```
117337909,some text,42930842,misc data,<xmlRoot><parent1><foo>data</foo><bar>123</bar></parent1></xmlRoot>
116425348,some more text,2df34as,blah,<xmlRoot><parent2><foo>data</foo><bar>123</bar></parent2></xmlRoot>
```

Comment: What are you using the regex in (language and/or application)?

Comment: Why not to replace every enter character before the </xmlRoot> element?

Comment: @Joe - I use either Notepad++ or Sublime Text 2

Comment: @JorgeCampos - The XML root elements are not always the same. They are finite, but there are quite a few. I was looking for a way to do it more programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
String result = yourstring.replaceAll("\\r?\\n(?!11\\d{7}(?!\\d))", "");
```

Pattern details:

```
\\r?          # optional carriage return (for windows format) 
\\n           # line feed
(?!           # open a negative lookahead (ie: not followed by)
    11\\d{7}  # 11, seven digits
    (?!\\d)   # not followed by another digit (to ensure that there isn't more
              # digits after, "1123456789" will not match)
)             # close the lookahead
```

Comment: Good point on the \r.  I'm surprised there isn't a generic linefeed-or-CR removing metacharacter.

Comment: @Joe: indeed, I don't think there is an equivalent to the Perl/PCRE `\R` in Java.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Can you break down the components of it a bit so I can understand what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Just search for this regex:

```
(?s)[\r\n]*(?!11\d{7})
```

and replace with an empty string, i.e., `""`.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, you can probably do this with the Extended Search.  Type the text inside the quotation marks, not the quotation marks.

1. Find: `"\r\n"`  Replace: `" "` [a space]
2. Find: `" (11\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)"`  Replace: `"\n\1"`

This won't work if you have other 9 digit numbers starting with 11, but if you don't this might be easier than doing it in regex.  Notepad++ is not very good at regexes spanning new lines from what I've read.